# Physics based Mathematica project ideas?

Tags: physics

I am looking to make a physics based Mathematica project. Ideally the project would take around 12 hours, gathering any experimental data and analyse the findings.

I'd have full access to university physics labs. The project would be for 2nd year physics students in the end and would aim to introduce using Mathematica in their work.

Comment: Sounds quite interesting, but at the moment the question seems too broad (and effectively lacks a question). Some users have mentioned RasperryPi projects in chat, e.g. @bobthechemist [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2234?m=12928893#12928893).

Comment: If you ask this at [Wolfram Community](http://community.wolfram.com/) I bet you'll get a lot of answers. I think there are almost certainly people who will see your post there who have tackled this problem before.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, I've never posted on the Wolfram community board before but I'm going to try putting this on there now.

The RPi project, building a spectrometer, was a great example thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please check Bobthechemist site for some ideas.

[BobtheChemist's projects](http://www.bobthechemist.com/)

Also, some other simple physics experiments done interfacing with Sensors and Arduino here.

[An experiment in moment of inertia](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/181641?p_p_auth=PThZ9lzq)

[Simple Pendulum Experiment](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/193779?p_p_auth=PThZ9lzq)

Comment: +1 This is by far the best answer I've seen on M.SE

Answer (score 4):

You could try making an intuitive explanation of Planck's constant.  There are a several formulae and plots to interrelate and explain, notably Wein's law, the Raleigh-Jeans curve, and then Planck's law.  Some plotting challenges.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_constant#Black-body_radiation

The result would be a nice explanation of the discovery of the quantum world.